# I am getting these errors after moving folders from a test folder to my public_html live folder

Tags: php, database, magento

I am getting these errors after moving folders from a test folder to my public_html live folder.

> **Fatal error:** Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /.../Page.php on line 67
>   **Fatal error:** Call to a member function checkIdentifier() on a non-object in /.../Router.php on line 90

This is what the lines look like

PAGE.PHP

```
$page = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page');
    if (!is_null($pageId) && $pageId!==$page->getIdentifier()) {
        $delimeterPosition = strrpos($pageId, '|');
        if ($delimeterPosition) {
            $pageId = substr($pageId, 0, $delimeterPosition);
```

ROUTER.PHP

```
$page   = Mage::getModel('cms/page');
$pageId = $page->checkIdentifier($identifier, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
if (!$pageId) {
    return false;
```

Comment: Is your Mage.php file included properly? (ie. include paths corrected for the new file location?)

Comment: I can't see any call to getId() in your PAGE.PHP code. Are you sure you pasted the correct code?

Comment: Would you happen to know which lines I should be looking at?

Comment: I moved the code inside the hostmonster server via there tools.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like w/e file the Mage class is in is not being loaded correctly. Check that your include_path is set properly in your php.ini file on your live environment and that the files are in the directories you expect if you gave them absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but it looks like you should be calling `getIdentifier` and not `getId`?  --  OR Rename `getIdentifier` to `getID`

```
$page = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page');
if (!is_null($pageId) && $pageId!==$page->getId()) {
    $delimeterPosition = strrpos($pageId, '|');
    if ($delimeterPosition) {
        $pageId = substr($pageId, 0, $delimeterPosition);
```

It's hard to tell without seeing how this is called, and what class `getIndentifier` or `getId` are coming from...